# Netbeans (7.3) - how to create a 'Java Web app' and HTML/JavaScript 'HTML 5 Application' in one project?

Tags: java, html, netbeans-7

I want to create a new Netbeans 7.3 project that will be based on the 'HTML web-application' project type, but it will also need to communicate to a server, so I want to add 'Java Web support', but they are listed as two separate project types.

How can I create a Java web app and add the HTML 5 support into it?  What are the steps required to create the 'merged' project types?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's not tightly integrated in Netbeans yet, but I was able to do it by creating the two separate projects and then going in to the Web Application Project-Properties and adding an entry in the 'packaging' tab (see screenshot).

[image]